# How to deep copy camera collection callback CMSampleBufferRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Obviously I must copy the `CMSampleBufferRef`, but `CMSampleBufferCreateCopy()` will only create a shallow copy.

The method is feasible, but the CPU consumption is too high!

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) copyPixelbuffer : (CVPixelBufferRef)pixel {

NSAssert(CFGetTypeID(pixel) == CVPixelBufferGetTypeID(), @"typeid !=");
CVPixelBufferRef _copy = NULL;

CVPixelBufferCreate(nil, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixel), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixel), CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixel), CVBufferGetAttachments(pixel, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate), &_copy);

if (_copy != NULL) {
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixel, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_copy, 0);
    size_t count =  CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(pixel);
    size_t img_widstp = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixel, 0);
    size_t img_heistp = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixel, 1);
    NSLog(@"img_widstp = %d, img_heistp = %d", img_widstp, img_heistp);
    for (size_t plane = 0; plane < count; plane++) {
        void *dest = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(_copy, plane);
        void *source = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixel, plane);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixel, plane);
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixel, plane);

        memcpy(dest, source, height * bytesPerRow);
    }

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_copy, 0);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixel, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
}
return _copy;
}
```

Comment: If the image size is constant then create the _copy CVPixelBufferRef only once (before starting anything) since it's allocation is very time consuming.